# Why does this custom hook return indefined in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i am creating a custom hook in React, this is my code:

```
import {useEffect} from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = () => {
            const data = url + "TEST";
            return data;
        }
        fetchData();
    })
}

export default useFetch;
```

It now returns some dummy value but that is just because of testing purposes.

Here is where i invoke my custom hook:

```
const Data = useFetch("https://customapiurlrandom.com/");
 useEffect(() => {
 console.log(Data);
}, [])
```

The thing is, when i check my console i see `undefined`. And i can't find out why.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you doing a `fetch()` inside of `fetchData()`? Your `useFetch()` doesn't return anything either

Comment: You're not returning anything. And you should use `useState` with `useEffect`

Comment: @NickParsons the final goal is to do a fetch inside fetchData indeed, how would i make my `useFetch` return `FetchData();` ?

Comment: Exactly what @ritaj said. Check here for a complete example https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom hook didn't return anything. You should add a state to keep the value and return it

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

const useFetch = (url) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = () => {
            const data = url + "TEST";
            return data;
        }
        setData(fetchData());
    },[url, setData]);

    return data;
}

export default useFetch;
```

And then use like this

```
const Data = useFetch("https://customapiurlrandom.com/");
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(Data);
}, [Data])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! This works. I find it so difficult working with normal logic inside React... because, why do i need state for this? State is used for the state of components right? And when de state changes the component re-renders. So why would state be needed here?